# Lua string replace wildcards

Tags: string, variables, replace, lua, wildcard

I'm trying to replace a certain wildcard string with another string using Lua.
That probably isnt clear so, here is my example:

If I have a string of a directory:

> C:\ possible changed dir name \ another change name \ known solid folder \ workingDir

It would end up like this:

> C:\ ROOT \ workingDir

Something that would allow me to replace the string between the root and the current directory. So the bold directory string would be replaced. Keep in mind the directory is variable, this is why it needs to have a wildcard to replace. So basically I know 2 "anchor" strings, but everything in between is unknown/variable.

Update: Strings are stored like this: "c:\\program files (x86)\\" will double backslashes affect the replace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)..

Assuming "known solid folder" is a constant, 
You can use the following pattern

```
local str = "C:\\ possible changed dir name \\ another change name \\ known solid folder \\ workingDir"
local toFind = "(C:\\).*(known solid folder)"
local toReplace = "C:\\ ROOT"

str = str:gsub(toFind,toReplace)
```

the `.*` in the toFind variable is your Wild Card. It gives all the characters between "C:\" and "known solid folder"

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly. I just couldn't seem to get the expression right because of the () around the ends lol.

Comment: () are optional only used for [Pattern Capturing](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html).. `"C:\\.*known solid folder"`  will also work just as well!

Comment: Also please aceept the answer, if you think it solves your query!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Why not return `"C:\\ROOT\\workingDir"` if you know both the prefix ("C:\") and suffix ("\workingDir")?</s>

Simple replacement should work, but you may need to be careful when "known solid folder" includes characters that have special meaning in templates:

```
function root(path, known_folder)
  local function q(s) return s:gsub('([%(%)%.%%%+%-%*%?%[%^%$%]])','%%%1') end
  return (path:gsub("^(%w:\\).+"..q(known_folder), "%1ROOT"))
end
print(root([[C:\possible...\another change...\known solid folder\workingDir]],
      "known solid folder"))
```

This prints `C:\ROOT\workingDir`.

Comment: Only `known solid folder` is known in advance.